# How to avoid using BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, .net-assembly

We are developing a web application which has tons of plugin dll files.

Now, we are able to load all the assemblies we need but we are using BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly while doing this. Which - I guess - causes a little problem.

The problem is, we need to update these dll files without restarting the application but these dll files are locked while application is running.

We are not using bin folder for these dll files. We are using 2 different folders (first one - ~/plugins - for copying files by us, second - ~/ptemp - folder is used for copying the files located under plugins folder and then loading in application like ones in bin folder)

As you know while application is working, you can overwrite the files in bin folder, so it means that it is possible to overwrite project assemblies while application is running.

After some research I found that it is possible by using private folder stuff in appdomainsetup but couldn't figure out how. (we dont want to create another appdomain, we want these files located in ptemp folder to be attached to main domain)

Sorry about my poor english but if you can, please help us.

By the way, some of these dll files includes some mvc areas.

We are using .Net 4.5, Mvc 4.

If it is necessary, I can post some code.

Comment: By the way, I figured out that the lock on files may be caused by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(pluginsTempPath); line. Any way, we can not overwrite these dll files in temp plug in folder and we need to. right now, it is impossible to update the dll's without restarting the app.

Comment: (Commenting more than 12 months after question): start looking into loading the plugins in their own AppDomains

Comment: Loading plug-ins in their own app domains is possible but you will incurr serialization/deserialization costs when data is being passed between app domains. Instead of the scenario being 'Execute something locally' it will become more like 'call a remote service'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we are doing:

```
var shadowCopyDirectories =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyDirectories;
        var newShadowCopyDirectories = shadowCopyDirectories
                                + System.IO.Path.PathSeparator
                                + HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/DynamicAssemblies/");
#pragma warning disable 618
        // Disabled compiler warning
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyPath(newShadowCopyDirectories);
#pragma warning restore 618
```

Basicly enables shadow copying of assemblies in the given directory to Temporary ASP.NET Files which means that those assemblies will not be locked. Have tried finding the non obsolete way of doing this but after searching for like 30 minutes I came up empty and didnt have the time to search further.

Still you can not avoid an application restart because:

1) You can not unload the 'old' assemblies from the currently running application, which means you are gonna be left with junk in memory and can face a kind of dll hell by having loaded two versions of the same assembly (e.x. Type A originates from Assembly 1 while Type B originates from assembly B)

2) You need a way to tell the BuildManager to recompile everything

But in the end you are probably better off enabling shadow copying because when recycling, a second worker process might be spawned while the first one waits until the second one is ready in which case you will not be able to update those 'dynamic' assemblies until you completely stop your application pool.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the best way to do this is an application restart

Comment: I guess so. Because these files are consumed by mvc itself too.

Comment: This doesnt really answer his question though.